# Android crashes after return back from another window

Tags: java, android

I'm working with an activity that has thread operation at the end initialize a new fragment. When running the application there is no problem. But while returning from another window such as settings, it crashes.

My code is as follows. Pleas mind that the actual error is ft.commit().

```
private void preHaberler()
{
    try
    {
        new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override 
            public void run(){
                haberler();
            }
        }).start();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        test(ex.getMessage());
    }
}

private void haberler()
{
    try
    {
        int sayfa = 1;
        int sayi = 10;
        int modul = -1;
        int ekModul = -1;
        HaberlerListModel[] haberler = Haberler.list(modul, ekModul, sayi, sayfa);
        final Bundle arguments = new Bundle();  
        arguments.putParcelableArray(HaberListesiFragment.ARG_HABERLER, haberler);
        arguments.putInt(HaberListesiFragment.ARG_SAYFA, sayfa);
        arguments.putInt(HaberListesiFragment.ARG_SAYI, sayi);
        arguments.putInt(HaberListesiFragment.ARG_MODUL, modul);
        arguments.putInt(HaberListesiFragment.ARG_EKMODUL, ekModul);

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
            @Override 
            public void run(){
                HaberListesiFragment hlf = new HaberListesiFragment();
                hlf.setArguments(arguments);
                FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                //ft.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
                ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter, R.anim.exit, R.anim.pop_enter, R.anim.pop_exit);
                ft.replace(R.id.main_container, hlf);
                ft.addToBackStack("bir");
                ft.commit(); // here is the error
//
        }
        });
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        test(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Here is the stack:

```
DalvikVM[localhost:8629]    
    Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception RuntimeException))  
        <VM does not provide monitor information>   
        ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 2180    
        ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 2230 
        ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 141    
        ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message) line: 1234  
        ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
        Looper.loop() line: 137 
        ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 5041    
        Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
        Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 511  
        ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 817  
        ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 584 
        NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]  
    Thread [<10> Binder_2] (Running)    
    Thread [<9> Binder_1] (Running) 
    Thread [<13> Binder_3] (Running)    
    Thread [<11> AsyncTask #1] (Running)    
    Thread [<12> AsyncTask #2] (Running)    
    Thread [<14> AsyncTask #3] (Running)    
    Thread [<15> AsyncTask #4] (Running)    
    Thread [<16> AsyncTask #5] (Running)    


***

DalvikVM[localhost:8629]    
    Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception RuntimeException))  
        <VM does not provide monitor information>   
        ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 823  
        ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 584 
        NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]  
    Thread [<10> Binder_2] (Running)    
    Thread [<9> Binder_1] (Running) 
    Thread [<13> Binder_3] (Running)    
    Thread [<11> AsyncTask #1] (Running)    
    Thread [<12> AsyncTask #2] (Running)    
    Thread [<14> AsyncTask #3] (Running)    
    Thread [<15> AsyncTask #4] (Running)    
    Thread [<16> AsyncTask #5] (Running)
```

How to overcome this problem?

Any helps would be very appreciated.

Comment: Is that your main activity?

Comment: Yes it is in main activity.

Comment: where is preHaberler() being called from?

Comment: from onCreate method. And I've tested onStart method, it remained same.

Comment: Log the exceptions and get the stacktrace from logcat. The thread snapshot you included isn't that helpful in the static context we have here on SO.

Answer (score 0):

You Activity needs to be created in order to perform any FragmentTransaction.

Please try to move you call into the `onActivityCreated` method.